# Install & Configure ActiveMq On Mac

Tags: macos, activemq-classic

Can anyone assist me with steps to install ActiveMQ on mac.
I have downloaded the older ActiveMQ and run command ./activemq start
its shows pid file created.

But when I try to access localhost:8161 from safari, it does not open.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I have observed this too,
what I did was,

Go to activemq folder on your machine inside the bin folder and do `activemq start` or `activemq restart`, after this the ActiveMQ instance starts correctly and you can access it using URL http://localhost:8161/admin (default location,might be different if you changed the configuration).

hope this helps!

Good luck!