# Why can't I get ActiveMQ started on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu, jms, activemq-classic

This is the exact situation I got in:

1. Followed the exact procedure mentioned in http://activemq.apache.org/getting-started.html in Unix Binary Section.
2. Extracted it in my home-directory and tested that it was working on terminal(following exact same procedures as mentioned).
3. localhost:8161/admin was working perfectly fine and then I messed up.
4. Moved the folder to /opt. And restarted it on terminal. It wasn't working.
5. Used ./activemq kill and ./activemq start to get it working again.
6. Things worsened after I changed its directory again to my home folder and I couldn't get it working after that.
7. However, I noticed that its working right after restarting my laptop, however, stops working when I try to open localhost:8161/admin

I am newbie and was about to get started on `ActiveMQ` and `JMS` to get prepared for an internship and it will be really nice if I can get some help here. 
Thanks.

---

```
redbot@Redbot:/opt/activemq/apacemq/bin$ ./activemq kill
INFO: Loading '/opt/activemq/apacemq//bin/env'
INFO: Using java '/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_91/bin/java'
INFO: not running, nothing to do

redbot@Redbot:/opt/activemq/apacemq/bin$ ./activemq start
INFO: Loading '/opt/activemq/apacemq//bin/env'
INFO: Using java '/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_91/bin/java'
INFO: Starting - inspect logfiles specified in logging.properties and log4j.properties to get details
INFO: pidfile created : '/opt/activemq/apacemq//data/activemq.pid' (pid '4527')
```

However, `./activemq` status shows a different story

```
redbot@Redbot:/opt/activemq/apacemq/bin$ ./activemq status
INFO: Loading '/opt/activemq/apacemq//bin/env'
INFO: Using java '/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_91/bin/java'
ActiveMQ not running
```

Comment: Check the log files in the data directory to see what the broker says

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/32604643/2551236

Comment: @Vihar
I tried that ./activemq restart too and this is what I got:

apacemq/bin$ ./activemq restart
INFO: Using java '/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_91/bin/java'
INFO: Loading '/opt/activemq/apacemq//bin/env'
INFO: Using java '/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_91/bin/java'
INFO: Starting - inspect logfiles specified in logging.properties and log4j.properties to get details
INFO: pidfile created : '/opt/activemq/apacemq//data/activemq.pid' (pid '5080')
INFO: Loading '/opt/activemq/apacemq//bin/env'
INFO: Using java '/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_91/bin/java'
ActiveMQ is running (pid '5080')

Comment: @TimBish Log File is empty. Do I've add something there?