# How to Install ActiveMQ server in MAC OS system?

Tags: java, macos, apache, installation, activemq-classic

How can I install ActiveMQ Server in MAC OS X? Is there anyway to get its installation source for MAC OS?

Here are some of source files, for installation but not for MAC OS.
http://activemq.apache.org/activemq-5144-release.html

Here is same question but there are steps for installation only. How (from where) can I get source for MAC OS?
[Install & Configure ActiveMq On Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32582856/install-configure-activemq-on-mac)

https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jms/activemq-tutorial-beginners/

I tried with [Unix/Linux Version](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?filename=/activemq/5.14.4/apache-activemq-5.14.4-bin.tar.gz&action=download) as suggested here by [Hemin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5901831/hemin).

Here is result of (console output) it:

```
> user:bin systemuser$ ./activemq start INFO: Loading
> '/Users/systemuser/Downloads/apache-activemq-5.14.4//bin/env' INFO:
> Using java '/usr/bin/java' INFO: Starting - inspect logfiles specified
> in logging.properties and log4j.properties to get details INFO:
> pidfile created :
> '/Users/systemuser/Downloads/apache-activemq-5.14.4//data/activemq.pid'
> (pid '787')
```

Then I tried to open http://localhost:8161/admin
But there is an alert (popup) window asking me for authentication as shown here.

[image]

I tried to enter system user/password but not worked. Can anyone help at this stage?

Comment: The default username and passwords are admin/admin. Did you try with these?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1) Download appropriate ActiveMq binary from [here](http://activemq.apache.org/download.html).

2) Unzip your bundle.

3) Open terminal and, set the terminal path to `ActiveMq -> bin`

4) Write command `activemq start`

5) Open http://localhost:8161/admin  to confirm Activemq is up and running.
You should have the following console.[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer with steps of installation. How can I get source of ActiveMQ for MAC?

Comment: There is link, which navigate me here (http://activemq.apache.org/activemq-5144-release.html), but no source for MAC.

Comment: @MobileAppDeveloper try to download and install Unix/Linux Version.

Comment: Tried and showing me an error at step 4: `-bash: activemq: command not found`

Comment: Thanks Hemin... I did it with your help

Comment: Log in with User: `Admin`, Pass: `Admin`

Comment: @Hemin It showing an error  "-bash: activemq: command not found" , Can you please guide Me?

Answer (score 26):

You can [install ActiveMQ with Homebrew package manager](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/activemq):

`$ brew install apache-activemq`

`$ brew services start activemq`

It will be installed in **/usr/local/Cellar/activemq/x.x.x/** directory.
(x.x.x = actual version being installed f.i. 5.15.10).

Open http://localhost:8161/admin to confirm ActiveMQ is up and running (default username and password: admin).

Comment: `brew install apache-activemq` gets the latest version.  How do I install a specific version of the ActiveMQ version using homebrew?

Answer (score 7):

Your steps are correct. but now as you are stuck with credential window. you can use **admin** as user name and password both. check below image.

Generally all default server has default credentials are set as **admin** for both username and password.

Hope this will work...

[image]

Comment: @MobileAppDeveloper wc.

Answer (score 5):

Well, for my local PoC-s I usually do it via `Docker`:

- Go to `https://hub.docker.com/r/webcenter/activemq` to look through the detailed instructions

Precondition:

- `Docker` is up-and-running on your host machine

Example:

- (in your terminal) `docker pull webcenter/activemq`
- (in your terminal) `docker run --name='activemq' -p 8161:8161 -it --rm -P webcenter/activemq:latest`
- (in your browser) Open the `http://localhost:8161/admin` and specify `admin` BOTH as login AND password
- **DONE**. Manage your topics / queues / messages.

Answer (score 2):

From ActiveMQ web console [doc](http://activemq.apache.org/web-console.html):

> Starting with ActiveMQ 5.4.0, Web Console comes pre-configured with
>   basic access authentication setup
>
> By default, you can access the web console with admin/admin
>   credentials. That can be changed (and more users can be added) in the
>   jetty-realm.properties file.

***jetty-realm.properties***

```
admin: admin, admin
user: user, user
```

Answer (score 2):

1) brew install apache-activemq

you need to go to this folder

2) cd /usr/local/Cellar/activemq/5.15.13/bin

3) ./activemq start

Answer (score 1):

The details on how install ActiveMQ in different platforms can be found here: [ActiveMQ->Getting Started](https://activemq.apache.org/getting-started.html)